# Looking to write a powershell script to run chkdsk and read results

Tags: powershell, drive, corruption, repair

I am trying to write a powershell script that will run chkdsk to determine if there is an error on the drive. If an error exist then it would run add the parameter /f and tell it to run on the next reboot. What would be the simplest way to write a script like this?

Answer (score 3):

Although PowerShell can handle old-fasion DOS commands (external and native system commands) it is best to avoid them if there is a better alterative available, as in this case: [Repair-Volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/storage/repair-volume) even I don't expect that it will add more value with regards to your specific task.

I don't think there is a clear list of general command alternatives and which one is preferred above the other, but I guess it something like this if you looking for a more direct interface with PowerShell:

1. [PowerShell Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview)
2. [.Net](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/) methods
3. [CimCmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets)
4. [ComObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-.net-and-com-objects--new-object-) methods
5. [Dynamic Link Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type#example-4-call-native-windows-apis)
6. [Pinvoke Win32 APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/pinvoke-or-accessing-win32-apis/)
7. System/External executables

Comment: Good to know about `Repair-Volume`, though its documentation mentions nothing about scheduling an error-correcting run on the next reboot.  Do you know if it _prompts_ for one if the target drive is in use (cannot be locked)? `chckdsk /f` shows this prompt _up front_, before even looking for errors, which `Repair-Volume` does not. Does `Repair-Volume` show such a prompt at all, only when actual errors are found?

Comment: As for the proposed preference order for command technologies: Only cmdlets and external programs are directly comparable with respect to level of abstraction and (ease of) syntax use. The other technologies may be beyond the skill level of the average shell user / scripter. If there's no PowerShell cmdlet available for a given task, calling an external program is a valid choice, and such calls are a core mandate of any shell.

Comment: @mklement0, with regards to `Repair-Volune`, I mentioned this cmdlet as it appears to be an "equivalent to chkdsk" for a lot of common features. I don't think it is able to do the whole task in once as requested in the question but at least has a more solid PowerShell input/output integration.  This was also the view point of the list I increated, but you're right: most of these technologies may be beyond the skill level of the average shell user.

Answer (score 3):

- [`chkdsk.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) uses distinct exit codes to signal the outcome of a run.

  - `3` is used to signal the presence of errors that weren't fixed due to not having specified `/f`
  - **Caveat**: **Running `chkdsk` without `/f`** (or any of the other repair options that *imply* `/f` - `/x`, `/r`, `/b`) means that the target volume isn't getting locked (which wouldn't be possible for the *system* volume), which means that "it **might report spurious errors**." (from the linked docs, emphasis added).
- In PowerShell, you can use the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) to query the exit code of the most recently executed external program (child process).
- You can schedule a `chkdsk` run with `/f` on the next reboot with a little trick, detailed in [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/798951/176094):

  - Make sure that the target drive is *in use* (i.e. that files on it are open); while this is by definition true for the *system* drive, it may not be for others:

    - Simply making a directory on the target drive the working directory in a `cmd.exe` session is sufficient, such as by submitting `D:` to target the `D:` drive, for instance.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - Then invoke `chkdsk /f`, which - due to the in-use state of the target drive - will *prompt* for whether the error-correcting run should be performed on the next reboot.
  - You can automate the response to this Y/N prompt by piping `echo Y` to the call.

To put it all together:

```bash
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

$targetDrive = 'C:' # Specify the target drive here.

# Run with checking only, not also fixing, i.e. do not use /f
chckdsk $targetDrive

if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 3) {
  # Errors were found, schedule a run for the next reboot.
  # Note: /r also checks for physical disk errors.
  cmd /c "$targetDrive && echo Y| chkdsk $targetDrive /f /r"
}

# $LASTEXITCODE should now be 0 either way:
# Either no errors were found, or fixing on the next reboot was successfully scheduled.
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
  exit $LASTEXITCODE # Unexpected error.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the text output from running `chkdsk` like so, and parse with regex

```
$data = & chkdsk
$isActionRequired = $null -ne ($data |Select-String -Pattern "No Further action is required")
if ($isActionRequired) {
    & chkdsk /f # <- amend to schedule
}
```

As I'm sure you know, this process takes a while, and the output will no longer show in the console (unless you pipe to something like [Tee-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7.3)). FWIW, I did not inspect the output of `chkdsk` in different states, so the above should be tweaked.

Comment: Note that it's always preferable to check process exit codes to infer success vs. (specific) failure. That way you don't have to scan the output, which is brittle, not least because `chkdsk`'s output is _localized_, based on the Windows UI language.

Comment: Makes sense, especially with your example above.

Comment: The code above looks like it will work but when I append /f I get a confirmation screen. Does anyone know of a way to confirm/bypass the confirmation screen?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this will work directly in PowerShell, but using CMD.exe, you can do "echo y | chkdsk /f" to pre-fill the yes response. You might try "Write-Host 'y' | & chkdsk /f" -- or just the earlier command through cmd.exe that is launched via PowerShell