# Native command throws error only when I redirect to a variable

Tags: powershell

I am using the following to get raw html code for a web page and then pass it to [html2text](https://github.com/Alir3z4/html2text) to then get only the text content, omitting the html tags:

```
wget -O - https://www.voidtools.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=36618#p36618 |html2text --ignore-links
```

It works just fine, consistently, a sample of the expected output:

```
...
vscroll_wide
scrollbar_back_color
scrollbar_back_dark_color
scrollbar_button_color
scrollbar_button_dark_color
scrollbar_button_icon_color
scrollbar_button_icon_dark_color
scrollbar_button_hot_color
scrollbar_button_hot_dark_color
scrollbar_button_hot_icon_color
scrollbar_button_hot_icon_dark_color
scrollbar_button_down_color
scrollbar_button_down_dark_color
scrollbar_button_down_icon_color
scrollbar_button_down_icon_dark_color
...
```

but as soon as I attempt to save the data to a variable or even pipe to `select-object` for further processing  I get an error:

```
$text = wget -O - https://www.voidtools.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=36618#p36618 |html2text
#wget -O - https://www.voidtools.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=36618#p36618 |html2text --ignore-links |Select-Object -f 5
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\ralf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\html2text.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ralf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\html2text\cli.py", line 330, in main
    sys.stdout.write(h.handle(html))
  File "C:\Users\ralf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u21b3' in position 202140: character maps to <undefined>
```

I searched around for this error but all of the solutions I am coming across are to do with navigating around this error inside a python script, I am in need of a solution of getting around this issue when piping/stdout

Why is PowerShell failing when redirecting the output?

PowerShell 7.4 on win 11

Comment: Although the issue is interesting, I would consider to avoid mixing python ([external commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76722508/1701026)) with PowerShell and use a cleaner approach with a .net based interface, see e.g.: [Extract text from html with powershell - bad pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75269044/1701026)

Comment: You may try setting `$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()` as the first command, but you may have to use specific parameters for both `wget` and `html2text` to force them to use UTF-8 output/input. That being said, I would propably do this task solely using Python, with its BeautifulSoup library making it easy to get only the text content from the HTML. It should be no more than 2 lines of code.

Comment: You converted data to TEXT so Select-Object will not work.  If you want to use Select-Object than remove html2text.  Select-Object with -f option expects an array.  So you can force an array using @()

Comment: @jdweng: `Select-Object -f 5` is short for `Select-Object -First 5` and as such simply selects the first 5 input objects, _whatever their type_. Output from _external programs_ - such as `html2text` - is invariably relayed _line by line_ by PowerShell, meaning that `Select-Object -f 5` selects the first 5 lines output by `html2text`, and works just as intended. Not only is your comment therefore irrelevant, the statement "Select-Object with -f option expects an array" - incorrect in and of itself - is likely to cause conceptual confusion.

Comment: @mklement0 : html2text is creating text.  There is no array in text (nor objects) so how do you get an array?

Comment: @jdweng: PowerShell relays stdout output from external programs as a _stream of lines_, i.e. one or more _strings_. Strings are _objects_, just like everything else in PowerShell / .NET, and `Select-Object`, which expects a _stream of objects via the pipeline_, not an _array_, happily trims the output to (at most) 5 lines with `-First 5`. Everything works as intended in this regard, and your comments are a confusing distraction to others. I guess I'm adding to the distraction, but my hope is that I can impart information that will prevent you from creating similar distractions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is PowerShell failing when redirecting the output?

The reason is that `python` (which underlies `html2text`) - like many other Windows CLIs (console applications) - modifies its output behavior based on whether the output target is a *console (terminal)* or is *redirected*:

- In the *former* case, such CLIs use the *Unicode* version of the WinAPI [`WriteConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) function, meaning that *any* character from the global [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) alphabet is accepted.

  - This means that character-encoding problems do *not* surface in this case, and the output usually *prints* properly to the console (terminal) - that said, *exotic* Unicode characters may not print properly, necessitating switching to a different *font*.
- In the *latter* case, CLIs must *encode* their output, and are expected to respect the legacy Windows *OEM code page* associated with the current console window, as reflected in the output from `chchp.com` and - by default - in `[Console]::OutputEncoding` inside a PowerShell session:

  - E.g., the OEM code page is [`437`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) on US-English systems, and if the text to output contains characters that cannot be represented in that code page - which (for non-[CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters) locales) is a *single*-byte encoding limited to *256* characters in total.

    - Notably, Python exhibits *nonstandard* behavior by default, by encoding redirected output based on the *ANSI* code page (e.g, [`1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) on US-English systems) rather than the *OEM* code page (both of which are determined by the system's active legacy *system locale*, aka *language for non-Unicode programs*). However, like the OEM code page (in non-CJK locales), ANSI code pages too are limited to 256 characters, and trying to encode a character outside that set results in the error you saw.
  - To avoid this limitation, modern CLIs increasingly encode their output using UTF-8 instead, either by default (e.g., Node.js), or on an *opt-in* basis (e.g., Python).

---

In the context of PowerShell, an external program's (stdout) output is considered *redirected* (*not* targeting the console/terminal) in one of the following cases:

- capturing external-program output in a variable (`$text = wget ...`, as in your case), or using it as part an of *expression* (e.g., `"foo" + (wget ...)`)
- *relaying* external-program output *via the pipeline* (e.g., `wget ... | ...`)
- in *Windows PowerShell* and [*PowerShell (Core) 7*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to v7.3.x*: also with `>`, the [redirection operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection); in *v7.4+*, using `>` directly on an external-program call now *passes the raw bytes through* to the target file.

That is, in all those cases *decoding* the external program-output comes into play, into *.NET strings*, based on the encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`.
In the case at hand, this stage wasn't even reached, because Python itself wasn't able to *encode* its output.

---

The **solution** in your case is therefore two-pronged, as suggested by [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42):

- Make sure that `html2text` outputs *UTF-8*-encoded text.

  - `html2text` is a Python-based script/executable, so (temporarily) set `$env:PYTHONUTF8=1` before invoking it.
- Make sure that PowerShell interprets the output as UTF-8:

  - To that end, (temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to `[System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()`

To put it all together:

```bash
$text = 
  & {
    $prevEnv = $env:PYTHONUTF8
    $env:PYTHONUTF8 = 1
    $prevEnc = [Console]::OutputEncoding
    [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()

    try {
      wget.exe -O - https://www.voidtools.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=36618#p36618 |
        html2text
    } finally {
      $env:PYTHONUTF8 = $prevEnv
      [Console]::OutputEncoding = $prevEnc
    }
  }
```

Note:

- When you pipe data *from PowerShell* TO an external program (not the case here), PowerShell uses the [**`$OutputEncoding`** preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding) to encode it, in which case you may have to (temporarily) change `$OutputEncoding` too; it defaults to ASCII(!) in *Windows PowerShell*, and to (BOM-less) UTF-8 in *PowerShell (Core) 7* - which is problematic in both cases, as it doesn't match the default value of `[Console]::OutputEncoding`.
  For instance, to both send data as UTF-8 and to decode it as such, you  can (temporarily) set:

  ```bash
  $OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
  ```
- It is possible to configure a given system to use UTF-8 *system-wide* by default, which would make things just work without extra effort in this case (though in *Windows PowerShell* you may situationally still have to set `$OutputEncoding`); however, this configuration, which sets the system locale in a way that sets both the OEM and the ANSI code page to `65001` (UTF-8), has *far-reaching consequences* that may break existing scripts - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).

  - [GitHub issue #7233](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7233) is a much lower-impact suggestion to make *PowerShell (Core) 7* console windows default to UTF-8, without the need to change the system locale (active code pages).